How to add a customized REST end-point to the Swagger?
While JHipster automatically populates the Swagger page with endpoints from generated resource/controller classes, customization guidelines recommend keeping custom logic separate. This means you might have created custom REST APIs within a custom controller class.
But how do you ensure these custom endpoints appear on the Swagger page?
